# probability winning lollies

Tags: probability

there are three cards facing downwards, only one of the card has lollies to be won. after a person picked a card, the host(who know where the card with lollies is) flipped over a card that contain no lollies. Then the person was asked if he is gonna change or card or keep the one he choosed.

What should the person do?

(this was the last question on my worksheet, which was suppose to be hard? but i thought the chance of the choosing the card with lollies was 50% anyway, regardless of whether he changed it or not? Please help! Thanks)

Comment: When only one of three cards wins you lollies, how do you get  a $Pr=50\%$ ?

Comment: hint: a person that changes will win if the original choice was wrong; a person that does not change will win if the original choice was correct. Now compare both probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

This is called the "Monty Haul" problem, and perhaps a little bit counter-intuitively at first glance, the answer is that the person should switch. They have a 2/3 chance of winning then. Have a look here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem

It becomes a little bit clearer if you imagine that the whole deck is laid out, and you are told you have to pick the Ace of Spades to win. You pick a card, and then the host goes through the deck  flipping over cards that are not the Ace of Spades until only one is left, and you get the option of switching.